# undefined control sequence \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I write my text in Mac OS X and every thing was fine but when I want compile my code with Winedt in Windows 7 Environment I got this error:

```
undefined control sequence \includegraphics[width=0.30/textwidth]{Hypercube}
```

I change `\` to `/` but Still got the error. And also I use package `graphicx`.

```
% GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES   
%  
 \ifCLASSINFOpdf   
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}     
 % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are       
   \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}{./image/}}    
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with    
  % every instance of \includegraphics      
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.jpg}   
 \else   
   % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx     
 % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no   % driver is specified.    
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}   
   % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are     
 % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}    
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with   
   % every instance of \includegraphics    
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}   
\fi

\begin{figure}[htpb]   
    \label{Figure::Hypercube}      
  \begin{center}    
 \includegraphics[width=0.30/textwidth]{Hypercube}    
    \caption{a Hypercube with 8 nodes}      
  \end{center}     
   \end{figure}
```

Comment: You need `\textwidth` since that refers to the width of the text block. `/textwidth` does not exist.

Comment: @Werner I change it to \textwidth but got the same error!

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: put the `\label{..}` _after_ the caption otherwise your reference will be wrong

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to make others to reproduce the problem. And don't change the error message, just copy it.

Answer (score 57):

You can replace that whole block of code with just

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and give the path with the image name

```
\includegraphics{pdf/image}
```

---

Or use the block this way:

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf   
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}     
   % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are       
   \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}{./image/}}    
   % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with    
   % every instance of \includegraphics      
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.jpg}   
 \else   
   % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx     
   % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no   % driver is specified.    
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}   
   % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are     
   \graphicspath{{../eps/}}    
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with   
  % every instance of \includegraphics    
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}   
\fi
```

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: then make a _complete_ example and do not show only fragments of the code ...

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Herbert's answer allows the compiler to switch between certain settings/options used by the `graphicx` package. This depends on whether you compile following a `latex->dvips` or `pdflatex` sequence. Which are you using?

Comment: @Herbert I can't put all the code here, and also when I open the file with TeXWork everything is ok. I just have problem with WinWdt.

Comment: @Werner I use pdflatex

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Then it is assumed that `Hypercube` has an extension `.pdf`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.jpg` and is located in the main `.tex` folder, or in `../pdf/`, `../jpeg/`, or `image/`. If this is the case, then `undefined control sequence` could refer to something else. Either way, as always, provide more context by means of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: You might want to start putting your image file and tex file in the same folder and simply comment out the code above. Just include `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` and try so we can understand that it is this code or the image file causing the problem.

Comment: the option `pdftex` is not needed and superflous

Comment: I solved this problem by just including the `\usepackage{graphicx}` package.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem. 
I wrote the `\usepackage` command after the `\begin{document}`, which was giving this error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{document}
```

is the right way.