# Undefined control sequence in TeXstudio even after bugfix

Tags: texstudio, epstopdf, miktex-update

I write my text in Windows 10 and using TexStudio. I recently updated both my MikTeX and TeXstudio to the latest versions. After the update the tex files that were working before start throwing the error

```
Undefined control sequence. ...raphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{network.eps}
```

Then, I found the following questions

[undefined control sequence \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25665/205473)

["Undefined control sequence \includegraphics" after TeXstudio update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515325/undefined-control-sequence-includegraphics-after-texstudio-update)

It seems like the root of the problem is same but the solutions that are suggested in those did not work. I realized that the problem happens only for eps files and if I include `epstopdf` the problem seems to be solved.

However, the latex was running properly without calling epstopdf before. How can I fix this issue without `\usepackage{epstopdf}`. See the full code below

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

test

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{network.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

The actual log message is as below

```
("C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\ep
stopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2019-12-09 v2.10 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\ETE@program@epstopdf ->\epstopdf@sys@cmd 

l.13 ...raphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{network.eps}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <network.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2019-03-28 04:44:41
(epstopdf)                    size: 141038 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <network-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: < --outfile=network-eps-converted-to.pdf networ
k.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 13.
runsystem( --outfile=network-eps-converted-to.pdf network.eps)...disabled (rest
ricted).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <network-eps-converted-to.pdf>.
```

Comment: You cannot add long text to a comment, please add it to the question instead. Have you fully updaed your miktex both in miktex user mode and in miktex admin mode?

Comment: If you compile with `pdflatex` then you don't need `epstopdf`. Also you should remove the extension `.eps`, so just put `\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{network}`.

Comment: @daleif I have even uninstalled miktex and texstudio completely (including configuration, preference, user files) and installed it only for one user. So I am sure that they are fully updated.

Comment: the error you show is not the format of a tex error message, and does not show which command is undefined. Please show the actual tex error from the log file, in a code block so line endings preserved

Comment: @Marijn that's my point. I shoud not need epstopdf if I compile with pdflatex but if I comment out the epstopdf, it does not work. I put the extension to be sure but without the extension the problem still exist

Comment: MikTeX can leave stuff behind that are then picked up when you reinstall. Thus the importance of the contents of the actual log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated the tex error message from the log file.

Comment: your log shows you are missing `epstopdf-sys.cfg`  in texlive that is `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg`  I am not sure where it is in miktex or whetehr it is missing upstream in miktex or just in your installation

Comment: You can also see the version of the miktex from the beginning of the log message

`
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.24)  24 JAN 2020 15:56
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg` does not exist in my pc since I am a windows user. Besides, I can directly use `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to workaround the problem instead of 
` \makeatletter \def\epstopdf@sys@cmd{repstopdf} \makeatother `. I am after an answer which explains the reason of this problem.

Comment: That is the reason, As I say that is the location of the file on texlive, I do not know the location in miktex, but the missing file is the reason for the error. I will change epstopdf-base.sty to default a definition in case the cfg file is missing.

Comment: https://github.com/ho-tex/epstopdf/commit/5c937d4fe92063b1eb35de607b122d57858ae71a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`epstopdf-base` currently assumes the presence of a file `epstopdf-sys.cfg` which sets up a system command to do the external conversion of the EPS files to PDF.

In texlive this is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
```

but apparently miktex does not set this default.

It is not good that the package *requires* a cfg file anyway so I will update `epstopdf-base` so the default command is `epstopdf`.

texlive's cfg file will still over-ride this, as now, and make the default be `repstopdf` unless you use `--shell-escape`, in which case it will be set to `epstopdf` (MikTeX does not make this distinction, apparently).

Until the package is updated (it is updated at [source](https://github.com/ho-tex/epstopdf/commit/5c937d4fe92063b1eb35de607b122d57858ae71a)), you can set this with

```
\makeatletter \def\epstopdf@sys@cmd{epstopdf} \makeatother
```